# Can I use touch input instead of a cursor with Chrome Remote Desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, mouse

I'm currently using my mobile device to access my laptop running Windows 8.1 via the [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en) app. It works fine, however I find it not user friendly having to drag my finger across the screen - in order to move the cursor - when interacting with my computer and coupled with the lag it becomes tedious.

Is there a way for me to make my laptop to go into 'tablet' mode so that I can simply tap on my phone screen and it will send a mouse click to that location without having to drag the cursor there in the first place?

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I did have a Huion tablet lying around and thought if I plugged it into my laptop I could enable tablet mode like in Windows 10. Might need to upgrade to try if this workaround.